# Webpack isn't resolving modules even though stipulated in rules

Tags: vue.js, webpack

- I'm running a vue instance in a php that loads the bundled `main.js` webpack compiles.
- I'm using a `webpack.config.js` in my project root and since my FE framework is Vue, I have the following set:

```
    const path = require('path');
    const {VueLoaderPlugin} = require('vue-loader')
    module.exports = {
        mode: 'development',
        watch: true,
        module: {
            rules: [{
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader'
            },
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [
                        'vue-style-loader',
                        'css-loader'
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    use: [
                        'vue-style-loader',
                        'css-loader',


                 {
                            loader: 'sass-loader',
                            options: {
                                data: '$color: red;'
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [new VueLoaderPlugin()]
 }
```

After downloading a [DatePicker library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@gravitano/vue-date-range-picker) and following set, after 1st compiling I got the error:

> `ERROR in ./node_modules/@gravitano/vue-date-range-picker/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/components/DateRangePicker'`

I've noticed that what fixes the issue is to add `.vue` to the required filename, **YET** fixing it here wouldn't make any sense and I need to apply the fix in webpack somehow, yet after seeing that I have vue in the config, i'm looking for other options atm.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `'.vue'` in `resolve.extensions`:

```js
resolve: {
    ...
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
},
```